# Google Docs delete document + copies

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am the owner of a google sheet that is shared with multiple people. I am not working on the project anymore and dont want them to use my work. I know that one of them made a copy of the sheet, before I removed them from the shared list.

Is there any way, to delete a sheet AND all copies that were made of that file?

Comment: Did you try looking at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://support.google.com/drive/?hl=en&authuser=0#topic=14940?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot delete a file owned by another user from their Drive. In future, you can change your sharing setting to prevent viewers (not editors) from being able to copy your file. [Source.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893)